# A question about almost sure converges.

Tags: probability

If we know $X_n \rightarrow_p Y$ and $X_n \rightarrow Z\space a.s.$ can we say that $P(Y=Z)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Because  $\forall \epsilon > 0$
$$P(|Y-Z| > \epsilon) = P(|Y-X_n + X_n - Z| > \epsilon) $$
$$\leq P(|X_n-Z|+|X_n - Y| > \epsilon)$$
$$\leq P(|X_n-Z| > \epsilon/2) + P(|X_n-Y|>\epsilon/2) \quad (*)$$
Take limits an $n\rightarrow \infty$ to get
$$P(|Y-Z| > \epsilon)= 0 \quad \forall \epsilon > 0$$

This implies $P(|Y-Z| = 0) = 1$.

Proof of $(*)$
$$P(|X_n-Z|+|X_n - Y| > \epsilon) = P(|X_n-Z|+|X_n - Y| > \epsilon, |X_n -Y| > \epsilon/2) 
+ P(|X_n-Z|+|X_n - Y| > \epsilon,|X_n -Y| \leq \epsilon/2)$$
$$\leq P(|X_n-Y|>\epsilon/2) + P(|X_n-Z| > \epsilon/2)$$
The last step follows as : $a+b >c, b< c/2 \Rightarrow a> c/2$.

Comment: Thanks! SO, can we say Y=Z a.s.?

Comment: Yes. Thats what $P(|Y-Z| = 0) = 1$ implies.

Comment: Additionally, if that epsilon logic is bothering you, you can replace it with $1/m$ and argue with that also.

Comment: Also, here we basically use the fact that $X\rightarrow Y\space a.s.$ implies $X \rightarrow_p Y$ correct?

Comment: Exactly. Convergence in almost sure implies convergence in probability.